# Getting an error when using npm to install a package

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to add a blog to my Gatsby website which involves adding MDX support. When I tried installing the [MDX plugin](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-mdx/#installation) by running the following command I get the following error:

**Command**
`npm install gatsby-plugin-mdx @mdx-js/mdx@v1 @mdx-js/react@v1`

**Error**

```
E:\Dev\Web\dantcho.com>npm install gatsby-plugin-mdx @mdx-js/mdx@v1 @mdx-js/react@v1
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: dantcho@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.9.0 || ^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0" from gatsby-plugin-mdx@3.16.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/gatsby-plugin-mdx
npm ERR!     gatsby-plugin-mdx@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.13.1 || ^17.0.0" from @mdx-js/react@1.6.22
npm ERR! node_modules/@mdx-js/react
npm ERR!   @mdx-js/react@"v1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @mdx-js/react@"^1.0.0" from gatsby-plugin-mdx@3.16.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/gatsby-plugin-mdx
npm ERR!     gatsby-plugin-mdx@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\dantc\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\dantc\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-06-18T01_43_31_526Z-debug-0.log
```

#### Additional Info:

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "dantcho",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "description": "Dantcho",
  "author": "Yordan Hristov (Dantcho)",
  "keywords": [
    "gatsby"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "develop": "gatsby develop",
    "start": "gatsby develop",
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "serve": "gatsby serve",
    "clean": "gatsby clean"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fontsource/rubik": "^4.5.10",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^2.0.7",
    "framer-motion": "^6.3.11",
    "gatsby": "^4.16.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-image": "^2.16.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^4.16.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^5.16.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^4.16.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-styled-components": "^5.16.0",
    "gatsby-remark-images": "^6.16.0",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^4.16.0",
    "gatsby-transformer-remark": "^5.16.0",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^4.16.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5"
  }
}
```

**Node version** 16.14.0

**NPM version** 8.6.0

**OS** Windows 10

**Update**

I tried to create a brand new Gatsby project and install the packages I need there. This way I could eliminate any chance of old/wrong versions of different packages. (This didn't work) I started having a similar issue with a lot other packages.

**Solution** (At least for me)

Switched to using Yarn.

Answer (score 6):

I have tried this command and it works fine for me.

```
npm config set legacy-peer-deps true

npm install  --force
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error when trying to install gatsby-plugin-mdx.
**It seems to be a dependency conflict between the React version (18.2.0) you have in your project and the react version these plugins are supposed to work with.**

So, the solution is quite easy:
*just downgrade your react version by editing your package.json file.*

Instead of this:

```
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "react": "^18.2.0",
  "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
  ...
},
```

change to some earlier version, like 16.14.0:

```
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "react": "^16.14.0",
  "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
  ...
},
```

Then, save the file.
After that, in your terminal run the following code to delete the current modules installed in your project.

`rm node_modules`

Finally, just reinstall your node_modules package by running the command:

```
npm install
```

Now, you can try again and install your mdx plugin:

```
npm install gatsby-plugin-mdx @mdx-js/mdx@v1 @mdx-js/react@v1
```

Hope it works you!

(I'm not so sure if downgrading your react might cause some side-effect problems, but this way worked for me. If anyone could clarify something about it, I'd appreciate)

Comment: This seems like the better answer. I like downgrading React more than forcing incorrect dependencies.

Comment: I also tried this other option, to force dependencies, but later, when trying to build gatsby project, I got an error with dependency again. So, I guess forcing is not a good option.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this Command `npm install gatsby-plugin-mdx @mdx-js/mdx@v1 @mdx-js/react@v1`
and it works fine with me

**package.json**

```
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@mdx-js/mdx": "^1.6.22",
    "@mdx-js/react": "^1.6.22",
    "gatsby-plugin-mdx": "^3.16.1"
  }
}
```

I think the problem will be in the folder path

Comment: I think it's an issue between the dependencies. No idea what tho.

Comment: Just tried installing a different library and can confirm that the folder path is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let's check the peer dependencies of `@mdx-js/react@1.6.22` package:

```
$ npm view @mdx-js/react@1.6.22 peerDependencies
{ react: '^16.13.1 || ^17.0.0' }
```

As you can see, it uses react package as its peer dependency with version: `^16.13.1` or `^17.0.0`. But in your project, the react package's version is ^18.2.0, which is incompatible. The warning will display when using npm v7.

Two safe solutions:

- Downgrade the react package to those two compatible versions. E.g.

```
$ npm i react@^17 react-dom@^17 -S
```

- Upgrade the  `@mdx-js/react` package to the latest version(2.3.0 until 2023.7.3) which supports the new version of React. Let's check the peer dependencies of the latest version:

```
$ npm view @mdx-js/react@2.3.0 peerDependencies
{ react: '>=16' }
```

It is compatible with react with version >=16. Obviously, `React 18.x` is ok.

Install/upgrade it

```
$ npm i @mdx-js/react@^2.3.0 -S
```

The `gatsby-plugin-mdx@3.16.1` package has the same version compatibility issue.

Since we have upgrade the `@mdx-js/react` package to `2.3.0`, we also need to upgrade the `gatsby-plugin-mdx` package to a compatible version. let's find which version is compatible:

```
$ npm view gatsby-plugin-mdx@3.20.0 peerDependencies
{
  '@mdx-js/mdx': '^1.0.0',
  '@mdx-js/react': '^1.0.0',
  gatsby: '^4.0.0-next',
  react: '^16.9.0 || ^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0',
  'react-dom': '^16.9.0 || ^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0'
}
```

`gatsby-plugin-mdx@3.20.0` demands the `@mdx-js/react` package's version is `^1.0.0`, it's not compatible. Let's find the `gatsby-plugin-mdx` v4's peer dependencies:

```
$ npm view gatsby-plugin-mdx@4.4.0 peerDependencies
{
  '@mdx-js/react': '^2.0.0',
  gatsby: '^4.0.0-next',
  'gatsby-source-filesystem': '^4.0.0-next',
  react: '^16.9.0 || ^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0 || ^0.0.0',
}
```

`gatsby-plugin-mdx@4.4.0` package is compatible with the `gatsby@^4.0.0-next` and `@mdx-js/react@^2.0.0`, we can use this version. The final package versions:

```json
"dependencies": {
  "react": "^18.2.0",
  "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
  "gatsby": "^4.16.0",
  "@mdx-js/react": "^2.3.0",
  "gatsby-plugin-mdx": "^4.4.0",
  "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^4.0.0"
},
```

But major version upgrading may break the code, you have to migrate the code to the upgraded version.

Note: Please be careful to run the `npm install <package>` with `--force`, or `--legacy-peer-deps` option, it will cause potentially broken. Instead, we should fix the version compatibility issues between dependent packages.

And npm official documentation about [legacy-peer-deps](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/config#legacy-peer-deps)

> Use of `legacy-peer-deps` is not recommended, as it will not enforce the peerDependencies contract that meta-dependencies may rely on.